# chartist.js library does not show anything

Tags: javascript

I would like to use `chartist.js` , But my implement does not show anything :

http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html

my code (`charts.html`) :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Chartist Tests</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="chartist.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Site content goes here !-->
    <script src="chartist.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
  series: [
    [12, 9, 7, 8, 5],
    [2, 1, 3.5, 7, 3],
    [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  ]
}, {
  fullWidth: true,
  chartPadding: {
    right: 40
  }
});

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

where is my wrong ?

[image]
**solved**

add this line code :

```
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```

Comment: Any console.log errors??

Comment: `TypeError: a is null`

Comment: well keep it as a proper answer...

Comment: ok. added as an answer .

Answer (score 2):

add this line code :

```
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
```